# Prove an elementary inequality

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

In the book Linear Integral Equations by Rainer Kress at page 138 is stated without giving a proof this inequality:

$$v^\delta e^{-v}\leq \delta^\delta e^{-\delta},$$
for all $v,\delta\in]0,\infty[$. I've tried to prove it, but I haven't succeed. 
 Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One has $\ln(x)\leq x-1$ for all positive $x$, and so in particular for $x=\frac{v}{\delta}$. Playing around with $\ln(\frac{v}{\delta})\leq \frac{v}{\delta}-1$ results in your inequality.

Comment: maybe you mean $ln(x)\leq x-1$?

Comment: @rafforaffo oops thanks.